# php regular expression how do i get last part of a string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a file `whatever_files_123456.ext`. I need to read just the number after the last underscore in a filename.  Filename can contain many underscores. I only care about the number after the last underscore and before the .ext. In this case it's 123456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/.*\_(\d+)(\.[\w\d]+)?$/", "$1", $filename)
```

Comment: Edited to support only letters and numbers on the extension. Also made the extension optional.

Comment: Don't try this at home kids. :)

Comment: @poojan Can you explain what you did. It seems like you changed it.

Comment: I have changed \.. to (\.[\w\d]+)?
\.. would have allowed any character after the extension (symbols and all).
(\.[\w\d]+)? limits it to numbers and characters. Also ? makes the extension optional.

Comment: Yeah. \. is the (escaped) dot. [\w\d] is a character limited to A-Za-z0-9. []+ ensures that there are one or more characters that are within square brackets. So it can't be empty.

Answer (score 8):

No need for regular expressions:

```
$parts = explode('_', $filename);
$num = (int)end($parts);
```

This will explode the filename into *parts* based on the underscore. Then convert the last item to an int value (quick way to remove the extension).

Answer (score 2):

If the number is *always* at the end, it could be faster to use `explode` to split the name up by underscores, grab the last item from the list, and strip off the ".ext". Like:

```
<?php
  $file = 'whatever_files_123456.ext';
  $split_up = explode('_', $file);
  $last_item = $split_up[count($split_up)-1];
  $number = substr($last_item, 0, -4);
```

But, if you do want to use preg_match, this would do the trick:

```
<?php
  $file = 'whatever_files_123456.ext';
  $regex = '/_(\d+).ext/';
  $items = array();
  $matched = preg_match($regex, $file, $items);
  $number = '';
  if($matched) $number = $items[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number always appears after the last underscore you should use:

```
$underArr=explode('_', $filename);
$arrSize=count($underArr)-1;
$num=$underArr[$arrSize];
$num=str_replace(".ext","",$num);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = '#.*\_([0-9]+)\.[a-z]+$#';
$subject = 'whatever_files_123456.ext';
$matches = array();

preg_match($pattern, $subject,$matches);

echo $matches[1]; // this is want u want
```