# How to remove the string after TEST from the filename C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc with extension

Tags: php, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regular expression how do i get last part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642470/php-regular-expression-how-do-i-get-last-part-of-a-string)

I want to remove the string after a particular string from a file name but with extension.In the above file name C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc,I want to remove the part -1349965063.After removal the file name should be C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST.doc

Comment: Yes. Please show your previous coding attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substr`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

This will only work if the first part of your string has consistant length:

```
$string = 'C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc';
$start = 0;
$length = 27;
$first_part = substr($string, $start, $length);
```

Then just add your extension back on the end.

---

Alternate suggestion for where length is not consistent:

```
$string = 'C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc';
$ext = pathinfo($string);
$parts = explode('TEST', $string);
$filename = $parts[0] . 'TEST' . $ext['extension'];
```

---

If the name is constantly changing but the hyphen structure is maintained you could explode on the hyphen. Then just ignore the last array entry as that is the timestamp:

```
$string = 'C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc';
$ext = pathinfo($string);
$parts = explode('-', $string);
$file = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++)
{
    $file .= $parts[$i]; 
}
$file .= $ext['extension'];
```

Comment: The first part of the string is not of fixed length

Comment: Alternate suggestion provided which does not care about consistent length.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc';
$str = preg_replace('/^(.*)-(\d+)(\.doc)$/',"$1$3",$str);
```

Comment: The file name is dynamic the string test wont repeat i just want to remove the number part whatever the string might be

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did :

```
<?php
$name = "C14-IMAGE-BACK-PREVIEW-TEST-1349965063.doc";
$new_name = $name;
$search = "TEST";
$position =  strpos($name, $search);
$ext = pathinfo($name);
if($position !== false && !empty($ext['extension']))
{
    $new_name = substr($name, 0, $position + strlen($search)) . '.' . $ext['extension'];
}
var_dump($new_name);
```